# Keras Tutorial Error: NameError: name 'layers' is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I am trying to follow [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) Keras tutorial, but I encounter the following error when compiling using the command `python3 test.py`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')
NameError: name 'layers' is not defined
```

My code is as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))

# Create a sigmoid layer:
layers.Dense(64, activation='sigmoid')

# A linear layer with L1 regularization of factor 0.01 applied to the kernel matrix:
layers.Dense(64, kernel_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l1(0.01))
# A linear layer with L2 regularization of factor 0.01 applied to the bias vector:
layers.Dense(64, bias_regularizer=keras.regularizers.l2(0.01))

# A linear layer with a kernel initialized to a random orthogonal matrix:
layers.Dense(64, kernel_initializer='orthogonal')
```

Python version: 3.6.6

Operating System: MacOS High Sierra

I am also doing this all in the command line `(tensorflow)$` environment.

Comment: Most probably you intended to write `model.add(keras.layers....etc)`.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti I copied it directly from https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras (See the "Configure the layers" section.)

Comment: Yes, it is explaining what it does inside model.add. It is not necessary.

Comment: You could consider reading the keras tutorials on [`the keras documentation`](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

Comment: @LucaCappelletti Oh, ok, my apologies! This seems like a better starting point for me. Thank you for the help. :) I will leave this just in case another newbie becomes confused in the future.

Comment: @LucaCappelletti Ok, thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What is wrong

First of all, python is signalling you that an object with name `layers` is not present within the scope of the script.

But the actual error is that the code was copied out of the [TensorFlow's Keras documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras), but in the documentation the second part of the code serves only to explain what is being instantiated within the `model.add(...)` call.

So just drop all the code that begins with `layers`, as it is just an explanation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

model = keras.Sequential()
# Adds a densely-connected layer with 64 units to the model:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add another:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
# Add a softmax layer with 10 output units:
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
```

### Further readings

You should consider learning about **Keras** on the [Keras Documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/sequential-model-guide/).

Answer (score 6):

For me importing layers with  `from tensorflow.keras import layers`  did the job.