# Traing a CNN using Prelu activation function

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm trying to train the model using `prelu` activation function, but I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py in zeros(shape, dtype, name)
   2965         shape = constant_op._tensor_shape_tensor_conversion_function(
-> 2966             tensor_shape.TensorShape(shape))
   2967       except (TypeError, ValueError):

31 frames
ValueError: Cannot convert a partially known TensorShape to a Tensor: (None, None, 64)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py in convert_to_eager_tensor(value, ctx, dtype)
     96       dtype = dtypes.as_dtype(dtype).as_datatype_enum
     97   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 98   return ops.EagerTensor(value, ctx.device_name, dtype)
     99 
    100 

ValueError: Attempt to convert a value (None) with an unsupported type (<class 'NoneType'>) to a Tensor.
```

I'm using the below-mentioned code, kindly let me know how do I correct it.

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, 
                                     GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Dense)
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow import keras

CLASSES = 2
#model.compile()

# setup model
base_model = MobileNet(weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
input = (224, 224, 3)
x = base_model.output
x = Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', activation = keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros', alpha_regularizer=None, alpha_constraint=None, shared_axes=None), strides= (2,2), name='layer1')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)

x = Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', activation = keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros', alpha_regularizer=None, alpha_constraint=None, shared_axes=None), name='layer2')(x)

x = GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)

x = Dropout(0.4)(x)
predictions = Dense(CLASSES, activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)(x)
model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)
 
# transfer learning
for layer in base_model.layers:
 layer.trainable = False
 
model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',loss='categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: Please update your question with the full error trace.

Comment: I added some necessary imports and reproduce OP's errors and add them to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tensor input is wrong. You need to set it up like this way

```
input_s = layers.Input((224, 224, 3))
base_model = keras.applications.MobileNet(weights='imagenet', 
                                 include_top=False, input_tensor=input_s)
...
```

Full working code

```
from tensorflow.keras.applications import MobileNet
from tensorflow.keras.layers import (Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, 
                                     GlobalAveragePooling2D, Dropout, Dense)
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import tensorflow as tf
```

```
CLASSES = 2
# setup model
input_s = layers.Input((224, 224, 3))
base_model = keras.applications.MobileNet(weights='imagenet', 
                      include_top=False, input_tensor=input_s)
x = layers.Conv2D(64, (3,3), padding='same', 
                  activation = keras.layers.PReLU(
                      alpha_initializer='zeros', 
                      alpha_regularizer=None,
                       alpha_constraint=None, 
                       shared_axes=None), 
                  strides= (2,2), name='layer1')(base_model.output)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2))(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(128, (3,3), padding='same', 
                  activation = keras.layers.PReLU(alpha_initializer='zeros', 
                                                  alpha_regularizer=None, 
                                                  alpha_constraint=None, 
                                                  shared_axes=None), name='layer2')(x)

x = layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(name='avg_pool')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.4)(x)

predictions = layers.Dense(CLASSES, 
                      activation=tf.keras.activations.sigmoid)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=predictions)

# transfer learning
for layer in base_model.layers:
 layer.trainable = False

model.compile(optimizer='rmsprop',
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Comment: tried the code, but ima getting the following error "input_s = layers.Input((224, 224, 3))
NameError: name 'layers' is not defined"

Comment: Can you check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51348085/keras-tutorial-error-nameerror-name-layers-is-not-defined

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask if you don't understand. And please update your question with the latest findings.

Comment: Sure i ll try that and let you know if im able to do it, thank you.

Comment: Updated the answer. Just add those imports. It should work.

Comment: got this error "tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [4,4,64] vs. [32,5,5,64] [Op:Mul]
2021-03-31 09:32:41.242699: W tensorflow/core/kernels/data/generator_dataset_op.cc:103] Error occurred when finalizing GeneratorDataset iterator: Failed precondition: Python interpreter state is not initialized. The process may be terminated.
  [[{{node PyFunc}}]]"

Comment: [This](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/19ClzF_VcmkHtiKU5TWdvR_i6EycysJBs?usp=sharing) the running code that you mention in question. Have a look.

Comment: [Code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/138CDan4e6NXpHPnvdjbTPem5fogRWGch?usp=sharing), i made the changes (still getting the same issue)

Comment: Access denied. Please share public access.

Comment: [Code](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/138CDan4e6NXpHPnvdjbTPem5fogRWGch?usp=sharing)  sorry for that

Comment: I see. Your training part is not the part of your question. If you run your code till `model.compile()` in the colab notebook, it will work with no errors. And that's the question is all about. For further, please ask a new questions with more details of your training data status - if possible with reproducible code.

Comment: sure thank you, but can you explain the changes you have included @M.Innat

Comment: Sorry didn't understand! what changes are you referring to?

Comment: l mean with the layers, you have updated the code.(above mentioned code code)

Comment: This is the class from which all layers inherit. `tf.keras.layers.`

Comment: I've added `from tensorflow.keras import layers` so that I can get `layer.Conv2D` etc.

Comment: But also as we have included all the operations like `Conv2D`, `GAP`..your can replace `layers.Conv2D` with only `Conv2D`..that will also work.

Comment: Okay, thank you, and i have a question, the google link i have shared (code), does it require major changes to make it work?

Comment: To make it work till the end, about that I can't say. I don't know what's your input like or related stuff. If you face an error in training time, you should ask a new questions with more training error details with providing some reproducible code. So that people can help.

Comment: If you have any query regarding your this question, feel free to ask. Otherwise, if it solves this question, please mark it as the right answer.

Comment: the data is fruit images. I have divided that into train and test set. Okay, i ll open a new issue. thank you.